# Why Am I getting a bigger time of execution while I added the number of threads executing the task?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp

I'm trying to improve the performances of my OpenMP code written in Fortran. In order to do that, I changed the variable `threads_list` from `private` to `shared` as you can see in the code below. My idea was to compute the elements of the `thread_list` array not only by the thread master (number 0) but also by multiple threads (the exact number is the `nthreads-2`). I was waiting for a smaller time of execution but no, the time of execution is getting 10 times bigger). I know that `shared` variables decrease the performances but I know also that increasing the number of threads computing a certain task increase the performances.
Here is the code of the subroutine where I use OpenMP:

```
  subroutine management_16_tasks(tasklist_GRAD,ww,pas,cpt ,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,u_prime_plus,&
       &taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab)
    INTEGER ::ff,pas
    INTEGER,intent(inout)::cpt,cpt1,nb_element,ww
    real(kind=REAL64)  :: dt,dx
    integer ,allocatable, dimension(:),intent(inout) ::p_element
    REAL(KIND=REAL64) ,allocatable, dimension(:),intent(inout) :: u_prime,u_prime_moins, u_prime_plus,taux,grad_x_u,&
         &grad_t_u,grad_t_f,grad_x_f,flux,sm
    real(kind=REAL64),allocatable,dimension(:),intent(inout) :: ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_moins,ux_plus
    REAL(KIND=REAL64) ,allocatable, dimension(:,:),intent(inout) ::tab0,tab
    type(tcb)::self
    !OpenMP variables
    integer::num_thread,nthreads
    integer, external :: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS    
    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master
    !Variables pour gestion des threads 
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::threads_list !liste contenant les nums des threads workers 
    integer,dimension(100)::threads_list_all !liste contenant les nums des threads workers dans l'ordre selon les tâches  
    integer,dimension(16)::threads_list_part3 ! le reste des tâches
    !=======================================================================================================================================================
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,threads_list_all,nthreads,ff) &
    !$OMP SHARED(tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master) &
    !$OMP SHARED(threads_list_part3,threads_list)

    num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() ! le rang du thread
    nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() ! le nombre de threads


    !Thread Application Master (numero 1)
    if (num_thread==1) then
       do ff=5,20 ! 16 tâches 
          if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true.) then
             tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff)
             tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
          end if
       end do
    end if
!!$    !$OMP BARRIER
    
    if (num_thread==0) then 
       allocate(threads_list(nthreads-2)) ! liste des threads workers 
    end if

    if ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then
       !$OMP DO SCHEDULE(STATIC,1)
       do ff=1,nthreads-2
          threads_list(ff)=ff+1 ! 2,3,..,nombre de threads-2
       end do
       !$OMP END DO
    end if

    !Thread Master (numero 0)
    if (num_thread==0) then

       
       do ff=5,20,nthreads-2
          if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_READY) then
             threads_list_all(ff-4:ff+nthreads-7)=threads_list(:)
          end if
       end do
       threads_list_part3=threads_list_all(1:16) ! 16 tâches
       deallocate(threads_list)

    end if
    !$OMP BARRIER

    !Threads workers
    do ff=5,20
       if (num_thread==threads_list_part3(ff-4)) then
          call tasks_ready_master(ff)%f_ptr(self,ww,pas,cpt ,nb_element,cpt1,dt,dx,p_element,u_prime,u_prime_moins,u_prime_plus,&
               &taux,grad_x_u,grad_t_u,grad_x_f,grad_t_f,ax_plus,ax_moins,ux_plus,ux_moins,sm,flux,tab0,tab)
          tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING
       end if
       !$OMP BARRIER 
    end do

    !Thread Master (numero 0)
    if (num_thread==0) then
       do ff=5,20
          if (tasks_ready_master(ff)%state==STATE_RUNNING) then
             tasklist_GRAD(ff)%state=STATE_RUNNING   
          end if
       end do
    end if
    !$OMP END PARALLEL 
  end subroutine management_16_tasks
```

I moved the part of the allocation of `threads_list` from inside the `if (num_threads==0) then` to outside. I changed `threads_list` from `private` to `shared`. The allocation is still done by only one thread. I added the filter `if ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then` and added also `!$OMP DO SCHEDULE (STATIC,1)` so that each thread computes an element of the array.

Comment: Why have you got a barrier in your main "Threads workers" loop? You have effectively serialised everything if I understand what you are doing.

Comment: @IanBush Yes, you are right. Even after retiring it, I still have the same issue. The only thing I changed was about threads_list.

Comment: Please update your code listing. Try to isolate a minimal example we could try to run.

Comment: @VladimirF Is it possible to put the link to a git in my question ? If no, I can try to isolate a minimal example.

Comment: No, it should not be possible.Still better than a link to Google Drive, though.  People do it, but most answerers will refuse to investigate such code behind a link. The question should here be self-contained. If it isn't, it is eligible for closure.

Comment: The gain with parallel execution is possible only to some extend. How scalable is the computation you are parallelizing? How many cores do you have on the computer? If you have more threads than the actual number of cores, you run the risk of slowing down the code; The overhead time the system uses to manage your threads could become prohibitive compared to the actual computation.

Comment: I have no idea how your program works to be honest - you have a worksharing construct `!$omp do` but you explicitly stop some threads from entering it. You are not allowed to do this - if you have a worksharing construct all threads must reach it, if only to satisfy the implicit barrier when they exit.